# Which one should be done first: multi-city flight booking or applying for transit visa?

Tags: tickets, bookings, transit-visas, london

I want to pass through London, booking a multi-city flight. Should I book the tickets first? Or should I apply for a transit visa first?

Comment: Always the visa first, as it’s not guaranteed. Unless you book a fully refundable trip of course.

Comment: If you post your nationality, route and any residence permits you hold, someone may be able to tell you that you don't need a transit visa.

Comment: Get the visa for your destination first. After it is in your passport, then apply for the transit visa.

Answer (score 1):

A transit visa - unlike a visitor visa - generally requires you to present the booked/confirmed tickets before applying. Thus you need to book or reserve the tickets first.

For UK, according to [official guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) a Transit Visitor needs:

> Evidence that your onward journey from the UK has been
>   booked/confirmed, and  that it is either within 24 hours of arrival in
>   the UK for Direct Airside Transit or 48 hours of arrival in the UK for
>   Visitor in Transit such as:
>
> - travel booking confirmation (can be email or copy of tickets)
> - travel agent confirmation